# Memory limit reached creating a thumbnail of large image with Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, thumbnails, imagick

I'm trying to create a thumbnail for a large image (8200x11800 px) so GD is not an option. I was told Imagick would overcome memory limits by using disk space instead of ram memory, so I installed it and rewrote mi script as follows:

```
$thumb = new Imagick ($sourceFilePath);
$thumb->thumbnailImage ($width, $thumb->getImageHeight() * ($width / $thumb->getImageWidth()));
$thumb->writeImage ($targetFilePath);
$thumb->destroy ();
```

But I still get `500 Server Error` with no message, same as used to happen with GD when memory wasn't enough, any idea? Thanks

BTW `memory_limit` is set to 512 MB and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zk2w3wqfnycc5d1/70x100.jpg) you can fetch the original image file.

Comment: Did you set MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT or modify policy.xml (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php)

Comment: please post that as an answer so I can accept it and worship you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the memory used by ImageMagick you should set one of the environment variables (e.g. MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT) or modify the policy.xml file. For more info visit the following page: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php